# Регистрация пайтон тг бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Кароче нужно сделать регистрацию и авторизацию в телеграм бот например я зарегался user:123456 накопил там 100 валюты например, и потом чтобы другой юзер тоже смог подключится к этому аккаунту, с тем же прогрессом, возможно так сделать?

Telebot, pyTelegramApi, Python

Comment: Например пусть первым сообщением вы будете отправлять login:password (или кодовую фразу, т.д.) далее загрузка данных по итогам авторизации. Минус что Вам нужно создать систему авторизации.

Comment: А можно объяснить как сделать систему авторизации?

Comment: Храните в базе данных юзеров. Накидаю пример структуры. Таблица User с полями id, user_id, name, password_hash. При работе с ботом, когда будет выполняться регистрация нового юзера нужно будет добавить запись в таблицу, где user_id брать из сообщения юзера, а name и password задаются юзером, причем password_hash вы сами считаете их хеша пароля (пусть будет sha256). При смене аккаунта другой юзер должен сказать тот же name и password, что был за другим пользователем и вы его user_id укажите в поле таблицы у существующей записи

Comment: Как выше писали храните все в базе... а данные программы подгружаете по ID (логину как вариант) если пройдена авторизация.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!!!!